# Design patterns used in the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

One way to increase your understanding of design patterns is to discover how patterns are used in the .NET framework.

Have you found any examples of design patterns in the .NET framework? In your answer please give a short description of the pattern, and example of how it is used in the framework.

**Example answer:**

The Strategy Design Pattern decouples an algorithm from the class that uses it by encapsulating the algorithm into a separate class. This allows for switching of algorithms.

The Sort method of the List class is an example of the Strategy pattern.

```
public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer)
```

By accepting an IComparer interface, users of the class can switch the sorting algorithm at runtime.

Comment: Community wiki please

Comment: I prefer reading a good book about design patterns. This is just reciting.

Comment: @WS - can't you find everything on SO in a book?  That's a little over the top.

Comment: @womp: Maybe it's just me, but I don't like questions that are asked just because someone might care.

Comment: @VVS: I like a good book, too. However I want to be armed with some expert knowledge before I blindly pick something up at Waldens. The opinions of this SO community are valuable and in this regard, I'm looking for what patterns I might want to be most/least concerned with. Btw, Head First Design Patterns is on my list - so, no you can't beat a **good** book.

Comment: Can we/I compile a uniquely bulleted list of the patterns in the body of the question with links to the answers?

Answer (score 6):

The [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) is used on the Stream classes:

- System.IO.Stream

  - System.IO.BufferedStream
  - System.IO.FileStream
  - System.IO.MemoryStream
  - System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
  - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream

The subclasses decorate Stream because they inherit from it, and they also contain an instance of Stream that is set up in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious one is the [Iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#C.23_and_other_.NET_languages).  using the [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb.aspx) class in the framework:

> Iterators in the .NET Framework are
>   called "enumerators" and represented
>   by the IEnumerator interface.
>   IEnumerator provides a MoveNext()
>   method, which advances to the next
>   element and indicates whether the end
>   of the collection has been reached; a
>   Current property, to obtain the value
>   of the element currently being pointed
>   at; and an optional Reset() method, to
>   rewind the enumerator back to its
>   initial position. The enumerator
>   initially points to a special value
>   before the first element, so a call to
>   MoveNext() is required to begin
>   iterating.

Answer (score 3):

This artical seems to be good:-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx#S5

Answer (score 3):

Here is vary good article of all design patterns which are used in .net framework:

http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2011/10/design-patterns-which-are-used-in-net.html

Answer (score 2):

`Events` in the .Net Framework follow the `Observer Pattern`

Answer (score 2):

- ADO.Net is all about Abstract Factory for getting rid of the details of connecting to data sources
- Events are an implementation of the Observer pattern
- .Net iterators are an implementation of the Iterator pattern

Answer (score 1):

[Adapter Pattern](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dtalbot/CustomDataAdapterDT12012005064359AM/CustomDataAdapterDT.aspx) in the [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.aspx) used with various data sources such as OleDB, Sql, and Oracle.